# passing same name keywords to functions in python

Tags: python, keyword, keyword-argument

What is the pythonic way of passing keywords through functions that have the same name as well as default values.  Simplistic example below showing 2 keywords being passed through a function.  This seems very long and not very scalable for large number of keywords.

```
from inspect import signature

def f_call(data, smooth=50, zone=0.7):
    # Do some stuff with the data
    data = "%s %i %f" % (data, smooth, zone)
    print(data)

def higher_level_f(**kwargs):
    # create some data
    data = "stuff"

    # check if params are in kwargs
    sig = signature(f_call)

    if 'smooth' in kwargs:
        smooth = kwargs['smooth']
    else:
        smooth = sig.parameters["smooth"].default
    if 'zone' in kwargs:
        zone = kwargs['zone']
    else:
        zone = sig.parameters["zone"].default

    f_call(data, smooth=smooth, zone=zone)
```

Comment: `f_call(data, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Fabricator - assume I don't have control over the definition of f_call

Comment: that's not the definition, that's how you call it.

Comment: OK but you can only call the function via f_call(data, **kwargs) so long as there are not other kwargs that are not present in the original f_call. For example if tou called higher_level_f(smooth=50, test=0.3) then that would fail